# How to fetch and use data from a JSON file in Angular7

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to fetch data from a JSON file and display that data in the form

JSON FILE Link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datameet/railways/master/trains.json

I am trying with the below code. But it returns following error in fetchdata.component.ts file:

> Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.

fetchdata.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetchdata',
  templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fetchdata.component.css']
})

export class FetchdataComponent implements OnInit {

  private _trainUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datameet/railways/master/trains.json
";
  items : any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.http.get( this._trainUrl)
      .subscribe(res => this.items = res.json());
    console.log(this.items);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

fetchdata.component.html

```
<select>
  <option  *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.properties.from_station_name">{{item.properties.from_station_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Please help.

Comment: Try `console.log(res)`? It is probably already returning the response body itself. You only need to use .json() if you are using the native fetch api

Comment: It is now giving another error: "Cannot find name 'res'."

Comment: I see.. I guess none of the answers below solves your problem too?

Comment: hi, @Tony7931 Please check the API response. you can get the object in response and that object pass into `*ngFor` that is not valid and also you can directly assign `res` to `this.items`. Like `this.items = res`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response probably isn't what you think. I suggest you console.log() the response of your query to see what it actually looks like:

```
    items : any;
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
      this.http.get( this._trainUrl)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.items = res.features; 
          console.log("Response", res);
          console.log(res.features)
        });
    }
```

You'll see that you actually get something like this in your console:

```
{type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array(5208)}
features: (5208) [{…}, …]
type: "FeatureCollection"
__proto__: Object
```

So you can assign your items to the `features` key as that's what you really need:

```
 constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
      this.http.get( this._trainUrl)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.items = res["features"]; 
        });
    }
```

Then your select options should show up.

Just letting you know, this isn't the perfect way to do it but it works fine for a small example like this.
I suggest you look into creating a service for any request in the future (doing it in the constructor isn't the best way) and have a look at the RxJS library

Comment: Thanks. It is working and thanks for the suggestion, I will have a look at RxJS Library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Angular's `Http` and `HttpClient` module and they are also exported differently.

1. **`Http`** -> is the core module which requires the user to call `res.json()`. This was common prior to Angular version 4.0.
2. **`HttpClient`** -> is new module since version 4.0. It defaults the communication to json and hence you don't need to call `res.json()` explicitly.

> In short, changing from `res.json()` to just `res` will fix the issue
>   for you.

i.e `this.items = res;` should be fine.

Also, as a good practice use the `ngOnInit` lifecycle method instead of the constructor to make any Http calls.

Comment: I am getting this error in Chrome Console and it is not showing any data in Select: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
I have written this: `.subscribe(res => this.items = res);` `console.log(this.items);`

Comment: It is because the `trains.json` url you are calling is returning a json object instead of array. And you are probably trying to iterate on it in your template using `ngFor`. Check the correct property and its type which you are assigning to the `select` component.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `.json()` function in case you doing plain `this.http.get`. Angular does that for you. Simply do `this.items = res`. That will do the trick.

UPD: your JSON object is not an array itself. You as well need to update your template in the following way:

```
<select>
  <option  *ngFor="let item of items.features" [value]="item.properties.from_station_name">{{item.properties.from_station_name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to do this: 
items : any;
  res: any;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.http.get( this._trainUrl)
      .subscribe(res => this.items = res);
      console.log(this.res);
  }

Comment: Just change `this.items = res.json()` to `this.items = res` in the code you've provided. `console.log(items)` will return `undefined` in your example, since http.get is async operation.

Comment: Now I am getting this error in Chrome Console and it is not showing any data in Select: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do `this.items = res.json()`? Why not just `this.items = res`? `res` should already hold the JSON object returned from the GET request. If it is indeed a string try `this.items = JSON.parse(res)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
private _trainUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datameet/railways/master/trains.json";
  items : any;
constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get( this._trainUrl).subscribe(res => {
      this.items = res;
      console.log(this.items);
    });
  }
```

Comment: It is working but partly. It is showing the JSON data in the console but not in Select. It is giving this error in console: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.